# procedural buffalo horn texture

Tags: texturing, procedural

[image: white horn glasses]

How to make these layers of horn (lines along glasses) procedural? It has to be simple edit, just change texture image and you are ready for render :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try colored spots, overlayed by white grooves, and also a bit of stretched bump:

[image]

[image]

Comment: we have to separate vector axes and make some magic I think :)))

Answer (score 0):

It has to look something like this, but don't know how to improve [image: V1]it

Comment: so what is the problem with this solution?

Comment: it looks not as real horn texture